# Measure multiple ROIs in imageJ

Tags: image, imagej, roi

I'm creating a script for automated measuring fluorescence intensity. I have done some progress, the macro opens the image, split in as many channels as I have and perform some trasformation so that it is possible to execute particle analysis at image 1. Then, what I want is to measure all the created ROIs but I am stacked at this point:

here is my code

```
 dir1 = getDirectory("Choose Source Directory ");
  list = getFileList(dir1);                                                           // get the list of all filenames in the directory
  subst = 3;                                                                          // set the "subst" variable to 3
  Dialog.create("BatchSplitStacks");                                                  // create a dialogue to change the stack divisor
  Dialog.addNumber("Number of substacks:", subst);                                    // in the dialogue, get the number of substacks, default is "subst" (=3)
  Dialog.show();                                                                      // show the above created dialogue
  chan = Dialog.getNumber();                                                          // the stack divisor is defined
  setBatchMode(false);                                                                 // do not show the images while processing them
  for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {                                                     // go through the files of the folder
      showProgress(i+1, list.length);                                                 // the progress of the processing of the actual stack is shown in the ImageJ window
      open(dir1+list[i]);                                                             // open an original stack
      name = list[i];                                                                 // get the filename of the original stack
      run("Stack Splitter", "number="+chan);                                          // run the Stack Splitter plugin with the defined divisor
      for (e=0; e<chan; e++) {                                                        // for each substack a saving routine is run
         dotIndex = lastIndexOf(name, ".");                                           // this line and the following line I took from another macro but I do not know 
                                                                          // substacks with a number below 10 are saved with a suffix and a 2 digit extension (e.g. 01 instead of the standard 1)
             saveAs("tiff", dir1+"c0"+e+".tif");
          close();
                                                                          // closing substack
      }                                                                               // next saving routine
                     close();                                                                   // closing current original stack

                     open(dir1+"c02.tif");
                                run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
                                run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
                                run("Enhance Contrast", "saturated=0.35");
                                setAutoThreshold("Default");
                                setAutoThreshold("Default dark");
                                run("Make Binary");
                                run("Make Binary");
                                run("Watershed");
                                run("Analyze Particles...", "size=0.30-50.00 circularity=0.00-0.70 show=Masks display summarize add in_situ");
                     open(dir1+"c01.tif");
                     run("Subtract Background...", "rolling=50");


        saveAs("Results", dir1+name+"c02"+ ".txt");
  }                                                                                   // move on to next original stack in the folder
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `roiManager("Multi Measure");`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can measure all ROIs in the [ROI Manager](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-30.html#fig:The-ROI-Manager) using the Measure button. In a macro, the lines are:

`roiManager("Deselect");
roiManager("Measure");`

You can learn more macro commands easily by using the [Macro Recorder](http://imagej.net/Macros#The_recorder).

You can browse all the available [macro functions](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html) online.

For more sophisticated per-ROI analysis, you can loop over the ROIs in the manager using the `roiManager("count")` and `roiManager("select", i)` commands. The [Scale_All_ROIs](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-legacy/blob/imagej-legacy-0.17.1/src/main/resources/script_templates/IJ1_Macro/Scale_All_ROIs.ijm) macro gives an example of this; you can easily load that macro into the [Script Editor](http://imagej.net/Script_Editor) by opening a new script (File > New > Script) and then choosing it from the Templates > IJ1 Macro menu of the Script Editor.